# get the result page . get Element b4a

Tags: javascript, android, basic4android

I wanted to know how to get the result page of this site

http://estelam.rahvar120.ir/index.jsp?siteid=1&fkeyid=&siteid=1&pageid=2371666

I'm logging in with Get Element, but I do not know how to display the next page. Please help me.

**I'm programming with b4a**

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these codes:

```
Sub Button1_Click
    extras.executeJavascript(webv,"document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].click();")
    StartActivity(act1)
End Sub
```

The button1 is the login button. 
When you click the button it begins an activity(act1) then in the act1 replace the "new URL" of the new page in webview.